# Netezza time formatting

Tags: sql, netezza

Need to convert timestamps with 1/1000 second resolution to 1/100 resolution. I could possibly use  `to_char(timestamp, text)` formatting function for this purpose, however need help with `text` to be used. Postgres way of doing this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42830627/3206440).

**input table** (note - the timestamp here is stored as varchar)

```
+-------------------------+
|       ms1000_val        |
+-------------------------+
| 2017/02/20 08:27:17.899 |
| 2017/02/20 08:23:43.894 |
| 2017/02/20 08:24:41.894 |
| 2017/02/20 08:28:09.899 |
+-------------------------+
```

**output table**

```
+------------------------+
|       ms100_val        |
+------------------------+
| 2017/02/20 08:27:17.89 |
| 2017/02/20 08:23:43.89 |
| 2017/02/20 08:24:41.89 |
| 2017/02/20 08:28:09.89 |
+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select cast(to_char(sub.field,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp) 
+ interval '10 millisecond' * (cast(to_char(sub.field,'MS') as integer)/10) as converted_value

from (
    select to_timestamp('2017/02/20 08:27:17.899','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') as field
    union 
    select to_timestamp('2017/02/20 08:23:43.894','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
    union 
    select to_timestamp('2017/02/20 08:24:41.894','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
    union 
    select to_timestamp('2017/02/20 08:28:09.899','YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
    ) sub
```